# How to open HDF5 file on QGIS

Tags: gdal, convert, saga, hdf

I've acquired an extensive collection of HDF5 files of Net Ecosystem Exchange data with daily temporal resolution. It seems that QGIS cannot open the file type by just dragging and dropping (while ArcGIS can).

One thing I tried was SAGA Mosaic Raster Layers with the following inputs [image]

But this fails with the window, "Unable to Execute Algorithm," saying "Incorrect parameter value for GRIDS" which I believe refers to the input grids (the HDF5 files).

I've also tried an approach to convert HDF5 to TIFF with GDAL Translate, but it won't accept the HDF5 file.

What approach can I take? My ultimate goal with this is to aggregate the data into monthly by averaging the daily data.

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like you don't have `hdf5` and or `gdal-hdf5` packages installed? https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIJTc.png